# Error while depolying contract in near ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nearprotocol, near, econnrefused

So I'm fairly new to Near protocol. I created a near app using

> npx create-near-app@latest

hello-near was the default name of the near app and folder so i just pressed enter.

> npm install -g near-cli

> cd hello-near

> npm run build:contract

So, everything above ran smoothly. But when I went to deploy it using the command

> near dev-deploy build/hello-near.wasm

And gives this output.

```
Starting deployment. Account id: dev-1660902746796-39871857513719, node: https://rpc.testnet.near.org, helper: https://helper.testnet.near.org, file: contract/build/hello_near.wasm
Transaction Id F7FWUEbKFqoWs9yNvk156bdmzWhHfnJ9exhWNHPREMAb
To see the transaction in the transaction explorer, please open this url in your browser
https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/F7FWUEbKFqoWs9yNvk156bdmzWhHfnJ9exhWNHPREMAb
Done deploying to dev-1660902746796-39871857513719
```

The transaction has succeeded. But right after this, it throws a long error :https://pastebin.com/5vZpN1HD

in short, it says ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my DNS. segment.io was not getting connected because I had adguardDNS. I changed my DNS to 8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4 and that solved the Issue and authentication was successful.